# how can I call function in the end of animation in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to call function (or set state) in the end of animation in my react native project.
how can I do it?
please help me.

my code :

```
import React,{component} from 'react';
import {Animated, View} from 'react-native';
class Animation extends Component {
  constaructor(){
     super()
     this.AnimationValue= new Animated.Value(0),
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(
      this.AnimationValue,
      {

        toValue: 1,
        duration: 4000,
      }
    ).start();
  }

  render() {
    const marginLeft = this.AnimationValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['0', '300']
    });
    return (
      <Animated.View style={{marginLeft}} >
        // ... my code
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a callback in the `start()`.

```
Animated.timing(
  this.AnimationValue,
  {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 4000,
  }
).start(hereGoesTheFunctionReference);
```

Answer (score 3):

`.start(callback)` is fired at the beginning of the animation.

Use an arrow function instead, *e.g.* `.start(()=>...)`